# Ubuntu won't do 1920x1080

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, resolution

Both my monitors (one over DVI other over HDMI) have a native resolution of 1920x1080 (16:9) but the only two options for resolution in the "Display" section of system settings are 800x600 (4:3) and 1024x768 (4:3).

The "additional drivers" tab in the "Software Sources" section of system settings tells me I have no drivers running, despite installing NVidia drivers multiple times.

I downloaded and installed Jockey from the Software Centre, which told me that I am running the NVidia driver. Since closing Jockey I am unable to find any trace of it in my system. I can't open it in Terminal either. When I search "nvidia" in the dash, I get "NVidia X Server Settings" and in there as well I have the same resolution options as in "Display" settings.

Additional information: With only one monitor, the issue persists. Mt driver version is nvidia-current, 304.64. Logging in with "Guest Login", I have all resolution options available, including 1920x1080. There is no `xorg.conf` file in /etc/X11 there is, however: `xorg.conf.failsafe`. I tried deleting `.nvidia-settings-rc` from Home and this had no effect.

I am running 12.10, both monitors are ASUS (Main:VH238H Second:VE247H) and my GPU is a GTX660 Ti.

Possibly related: When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I am prompted to login, then the screen fades to black. Same issue occurs when I use "Big Picture" mode in Steam.

What's strange is that it seems the login screen is at proper resolution, and right after logging in, I get this message:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Now put all this relevant information in your question. And then let's clean up the comments. It's not a discussion forum. :) Still open: 3) What happens in a new user or Guest account?

Comment: Then the only reason I can think of for failure in your account is a left-over per-user Nvidia settings file. There must be some `~/.nvidia-settings-rc` there!

Comment: No, in your home directory, `~` points to your homedir and `.`-prefixed files are hidden. Verify in your terminal (as user, not root/sudo!): `ls -al ~/.nvidia-settings-rc`

Comment: I deleted it and after logging out and back in, still the same.

Comment: @Dan You have just got to delete your nvidia drivers and try the answer provided here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/442851/how-can-i-get-my-monitors-maximum-resolution-without-the-proprietary-amd-graphic-driver-installed Remember that your lightdm file will be as /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf instead of being as /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf . So wherever the answer says to modify /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf you have to modify /etc/lightdm/lighdm.conf

Answer (score 0):

a quick fix that may or may not work is try making a new user, this will force the x.org to reconfigure along with the Nvidia settings; At-least for that particular user.

if anything this wont really fix your problem, just a possible short term work around.

you can do this to your current user by trying dpkg-reconfigure x.org (also to nvidia-settings)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like that too. I fixed it by removing 
`/etc/X11/xorg.conf` `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe` and `/etc/X11/xorg.backup`. 
Nvidia drivers can be a real pain in the backside sometimes.
Remember to remove those files using sudo, otherwise you can't remove them.