# Resolution after installation is lost

Tags: drivers, nvidia, live-usb, resolution, nouveau

I tried to install Ubuntu into a computer with a Nvidia 7100 graphics.

The **LiveUSB has a perfect resolution and a perfect response** by default.

**But after the installation**, the **desktop has a resolution of 800x640**. I have to install the nouveau or proprietary driver for fixing that. Both of them have a right response with Unity, but not perfect :(

Why has the LiveUSB a right resolution? **Could I reply that resolution after the installation** without the `nouveau` or `nvidia` driver? Just like the Live Desktop is doing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What resolution do you want to have?

Comment: It wasn't my computer and it was yesterday. I think it was 1280x1024 :)

Comment: Please refer to the accepted answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/448045/low-resolution-on-lubuntu/448113#448113