# Increase laptop screen resolution over 1024x768 on HP Compaq Presario v3000

Tags: 12.04, screen, intel, compaq, display-resolution

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04.
The default display driver has fixed my resolution to 1024x768. The only other option I see for selection is 800x600. 
Is there a way to increase my resolution to see 1280x800 as many sites recommend? My desktop is not using the full screen. It's sticking to the left side. Have about 4 inches of dark unused area to my right.

Have been trying to configure this since 3 days. No progress made so far :-(

As per some of the suggestions in the comments, I tried the following steps.

```
Step 1: cvt 1280 800
Output:
```

`# 1280x800 59.81 Hz (CVT 1.02MA) hsync: 49.70 kHz; pclk: 83.50 MHzModeline "1280x800_60.00"   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 -hsync +vsync`

```
Step 2: xrandr --newmode "1280x800_60.00"   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 -hsync +vsync

Step 3: xrandr --verbose --addmode LVDS1 1280x800_60.0
Output: 
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) 
Major opcode of failed request:  149 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  27
Current serial number in output stream:  28
```

Is this due to refresh rate? My xrandr gives the following output now:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
LVDS1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm

1024x768       60.0*+
800x600        60.3     56.2
640x480        59.9

VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1280x800_60.00 (0xd5)   83.5MHz
h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock   49.7KHz
v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock   59.8Hz
```

Comment: Do you know which GPU your laptop has ?

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

Answer (score 0):

ONLY If installing drivers for your GPU doesnt help. [Should be at Software & Updates >> additional drivers]
Try looking here : [How to make my maximum screen resolution to be detected by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448045/low-resolution-on-lubuntu?noredirect=1#comment588244_448045) Look at the answer provided by Venki
I had the same problem and that helped me. But on the first command instead of :

```
cvt 2048 1536
```

I used:

```
gtf 1280 1024 60
```

gtf [horizontal res] [vertical res] [refresh rate]

If you get odd looking fonts after following the linked post, use :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fontconfig-infinality
```

Not sure if that package above will help but it did help me. 
If it doesnt you can uninstall it by:
sudo apt-get remove --purge fontconfig-infinality
sudo ppa-purge ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa

Comment: cvt 1280 800 .. didn't help too.

Comment: Hmm dude I think you have a typo. Looking at your post I see: --newmode "1280x800_60.00" but when you did --addmode you typed 1280x800_60.0 missing a 0 , I hope that's the problem. Sorry it took me this long to reply ;s

Comment: Hi Kyodo! Thanks for checking back. I tried with an extra 0. I get a similar error. "X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  27
  Current serial number in output stream:  28"

Comment: xrandr --fb 1280x800 does this work ?

Comment: It doesn't go beyond 1024x768. No effect even if I give bigger values.

Answer (score 0):

12.04 additional drivers should offer an Nvidia driver for your geforce 6150 gpu,  The one to use is current,  driver 304.117.  Then you can use the "Nvidia X server settings" program to adjust the resolution to 1280x800.  In 14.04, the drivers are found under the "software and updates" program's 4 tab.

Comment: My graphics controller is : 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)