# Restoring higher resolution after installing ubuntu 14.04 with nomodset

Tags: system-installation, thinkpad, nomodeset, display-resolution

I've installed ubuntu 14.04 on my Thinkpad T420 which has Nvidia optimus GPU, using nomodset option but after installation I'm not able to get the full resolution. Can someone please guide me how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Please refer to this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/448045/low-resolution-on-lubuntu/448113#448113 .It might work(I am assuming you just have the default open source drivers)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install the proprietary NVIDIA-drivers. There should not be any problems with NVIDIA Optimus in Ubuntu 14.04 (as far as I remember there were some problems in 12.04).

(The drivers should be available in the pre-installed program 'additional drivers'. These drivers are not the very newest, but should work well and are easy to install.)

Comment: I tried installing the 331-updates and it seems to work fine if I've discrete graphics(only nvidia) option enabled in BIOS. But when I rebooted with optimus, after logging in, unity and X server seems to freeze.