# Resolution problems Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, resolution, monitor

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and everything is working fine exept for the resolution, my monitor supports 1440x900 but in the options only allows 800x640 and 1024x768, I tryed the xorg.conf solution and it doesn't work

EDIT: Problem solved! I installed the propietary drivers from the "Aditional Drivers" option and now works :D

Comment: I suspect it is related to your VGA driver. Is it already installed?

Comment: I have an AMD HD 7750, I tryed the open drivers and the propietary drivers same problem.

Comment: @Darthkpo AS i said in my other question of yours , you actually **may not** need drivers at all to detect your maximum screen resolution! You saw [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/448045/how-to-make-my-maximum-screen-resolution-to-be-detected-by-ubuntu/448113#448113)? Did you try that? Did it work?(BTW if you want to try that you must delete your proprietary driver) I am recommending you not to install the proprietary drivers as at times it **may** (emphasis on *may*) cause some screen tearing issues. You better go with the open source drivers. Free advice! Your option to listen or  not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It often works best to set the resolution in the software provided by the proprietary graphics drivers if available. Use Nvidia X Server Display Settings or AMD Catalyst Control Center.

[Nvidia Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)

[image]

By clicking the icon you will be taken to a dialog where you can choose which version you want to install, choose the recommended driver.

[image]

Set the resolution by running the Nvidia X Server Settings app...
[image]

If you have an ATI/AMD card, then see the [AMD Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD).

Comment: probably provide a screen shot of the driver software? And add info on how to actually change the resolution from there? Will make this answer way better(to attract up votes if you want some)!