# AMD Drivers problem: can't display the resolution

Tags: drivers, 14.04, ati, radeon

So, I'm kind of new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, I installed the latest (Ubuntu 14.04) and everything went fine, except  for the resolution so I thought that it was a driver problem because I have a **AMD HD 7750** and maybe it required additional proprietary drivers so I installed **AMD Catalyst (Latest version)**, and then rebooted.

And now my monitor says `Can't Display` and I can't see the GUI.

I can go to terminal (Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> etc) but Not the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that when you installed the proprietary driver, Unity selected a resolution beyond your monitor's maximum resolution. That is why your monitor says `Can't Display`. Therefore all you gotta do is just change your resolution!

For this:

- When you are in that `Can't Display` screen check if you can hear the login sound.
   This would tell us if you are in your login screen.
- Then type in your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Now we will assume we are in the desktop screen. Now try opening a terminal(with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>).
  Then type the following command:

  ```
  xrandr -s 1024x768
  ```

  I am assuming `1024x768` is a supported resolution in your monitor. If its not supported then type some other supported resolution. This should show your desktop.

If this doesn't work then I suppose you can just delete your proprietary driver. Since you say that your purpose for installing the driver is just to get your maximum screen resolution detected you can just delete it and get your maximum screen resolution detected by following the steps in the answers whose links are as follows(The first link is better):

1. [How to make my maximum screen resolution to be detected by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448045/how-to-make-my-maximum-screen-resolution-to-be-detected-by-ubuntu/448113#448113)
2. [How can I get my monitor's maximum resolution without the proprietary AMD graphic driver installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442851/how-can-i-get-my-monitors-maximum-resolution-without-the-proprietary-amd-graphi)

Comment: I am assuming that I need not give context for my links as both the links are AU answers. Yet if its required I give context please feel free to comment!

Comment: Great! And after trying please get back to me and tell if it **doesn't** work. If it works you can just press the accept icon(a tick mark) and accept the answer(which will tell the community that this issue was solved by this answer).

Answer (score 1):

There's a good link for getting past this problem on this question:
[*My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).

What you need to do, is at the Grub boot screen, choose Ubuntu boot options, and start the recovery mode.  This opens in a text based display.

1. Choose network - this takes some time to complete
2. Choose root - this drops you into a terminal window
3. Enter these commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri fglrx-modaliases
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core`
   ```

This removes the proprietary driver, and ensures the open source drivers are loaded.
Then type:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: @CharlesGreen Why do you have to get into GRUB to uninstall the AMD drivers? You can just use `sudo aticonfig --uninstall` from a tty as far as i know.

Comment: Hi @Venki  - not into grub and editing the bootloader, but an option at boot time that allows you to drop into a tty and perform these commands.  I may not be precise enough in my terminology, but I am trying!  The 'network' choice mounts the disks in rw mode, and connects to the internet should you need to add drivers and programs, and of course the 'root' choice then takes you to a tty where various commands can be executed.  The link in the answer 'My computer...' has a series of pretty pictures which makes it very clear.

Comment: Ok. I get it. But you can drop into a tty with Ctrl+Alt+F1 ! Anyways you are right. But then, its not a blank screen error here! Its a `Can't Display` error(i.e not a blank screen. There is text on the screen!) So I gave my own answer above. Anyways I like your answer! Since it easily allows one to connect to the internet from a command line and install other drivers. Deserves an upvote!

Comment: Yeah, but that generally only works if you can get past the boot screens - he indicated he couldn't get to the point of to GUI starting.  I think he's updated the question since, or at least I didn't notice that he was able to get to the tty.